# Typescript & D3.js: transformation of Type Link by SimulationLinkDatum not recognised

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, types

I am trying to integrate a D3.js Network Diagram into a react app. When I create an exact clone of a (working) example code from [ https://github.com/holtzy/react-graph-gallery/tree/main/viz/NetworkDiagramBasicCanvas](  the react-graph-gallery github page), I receive the following Typescript error at the .x and .y of the following code block in drawNetwork.ts of the example: 'Property 'x' does not exist on type 'string'.'

```
  // Draw the links first
  links.forEach((link) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(link.source.x, link.source.y);
    context.lineTo(link.target.x, link.target.y);
    context.stroke();
  });
```

I understand that the interface of Link as defined in data.ts should enable Link to transform from having property string, into an interface that holds an .x and .y property through d3.SimulationLinkDatum:

```
export interface Link extends d3.SimulationLinkDatum<Node> {
  source: string;
  target: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Why is this not happening or not recognised? Is there a work around? Thank you very much for your help!